# Can I purchase a domain separately from hosting and put them together later?

Tags: domains, web-hosting, purchase

I want to create a blog with my own domain.  I will need to purchase both the domain name and hosting for the blog.

What is the difference between the purchasing a domain only and the purchasing both a the domain and a hosting service together?

Could I purchase the domain only to lock it and add the hosting service later?

Comment: I think this question suggests opinions because you're asking about which order to purchase things in and I believe theres no order while others could say buy this first then that second.

Comment: I removed the part of this question that wasking asking for opnions and re-opened it.